# limiting character in textbox

Tags: jquery

I have textbox to enter only alphabet and numerical values. I do not want use plugin. Is it possible'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(":text").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this...
[Sweet Validation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasad_1/RegExpPSD12062005021717AM/RegExpPSD.aspx)